# Updating a base entity that has many to many relation without retrieving the data in the junction table

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a Users table, along with Roles table with many to many relation

Users

```
Id, Name, Password, ICollection<Role> ....
```

Roles

```
Id, Name
```

and UsersRoles

```
UserId, RoleId
```

Now if I retrieve a user object from the database and modify the Password field of example, an exception will occur if i don't load the roles even though I'm not touching the roles of the user.

So the question is: how can I update the Users table without retrieving all the roles every time?

Comment: What code are you trying in the update? Something like `var user = context.Users.Find(userId);  user.Password = 'newPassword'; context.SaveChanges();` should work.

Comment: @SteveGreene It throws an exception since the roles collection is marked as required.

Comment: How do you require a collection? That's not supported in EF (since it's not supported if SQL)- you need to do that with validation. Show your models and code...

Comment: @SteveGreene I am doing that with validation: `[Required]
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }`